# Perl generating error message with mojibake

Tags: perl

I'm learning Perl and in the system console I'm executing a script that shows the following weird characters:

```
open(my $fh, '<', 'teste') or warn $!
Arquivo ou diretÃ³rio nÃ£o encontrado at reply input line 1.
```

The message should be: `Arquivo ou diretório não encontrado at reply input line 1.`

I think that it's [iso-8859-1](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8859-1).

I would like to have everything UTF-8 encoded/interpreted so I've learned to put the following lines in the source:

```
use open qw/:std :utf8/; # entrada e saída em utf8                                                                                         
use utf8; # código fonte em utf8
```

On my system I've:

```
LANG=pt_BR.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=pt_BR:pt:en
LC_CTYPE=pt_BR.UTF-8
LC_NUMERIC="pt_BR.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="pt_BR.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="pt_BR.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="pt_BR.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="pt_BR.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="pt_BR.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="pt_BR.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="pt_BR.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="pt_BR.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="pt_BR.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="pt_BR.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

My terminal is handled by [putty](http://www.putty.org/).

How to solve this?

Comment: Which terminal are you using?

Comment: Good question @MattJacob: putty. But I can tell you that **Translation** > **Remote character set** is UTF-8 is there anything more that I must set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It wasn't Perl, it was the terminal settings.

As @MattJacob pointed out it could the terminal.

I just made a test dumping the registry:

```
regedit /ea "D:\putty.reg.old" HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\SimonTatham\PuTTY\Sessions
```

**The GUI of putty in the Translation > Remote character set was showing by default UTF-8 encoding. But it was not set**. So I just change it to whatever encoding, saved the session and saved it again into putty.reg to do file comparison.

```
fc putty.reg.old putty.reg
***** putty.reg.old
"Wordness224"="2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2"
"LineCodePage"=""
"CJKAmbigWide"=dword:00000000
***** PUTTY.REG
"Wordness224"="2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2"
"LineCodePage"="ISO-8859-1:1998 (Latin-1, West Europe)"
"CJKAmbigWide"=dword:00000000
*****
```

Now we see that the "LineCodePage"="" was empty. Selecting UTF-8 now should work!

```
fc putty.reg.old putty.reg
***** putty.reg.old
"Wordness224"="2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2"
"LineCodePage"=""
"CJKAmbigWide"=dword:00000000
***** PUTTY.REG
"Wordness224"="2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2"
"LineCodePage"="UTF-8"
"CJKAmbigWide"=dword:00000000
*****
```

Lets get into the server and test!

```
~(master ✗) perl -e 'open(my $fh, "<", "teste") or warn $!'
Arquivo ou diretório não encontrado at -e line 1.
```